# Github - original author pushing to forked branch

Tags: git, github

On Github - So I forked a branch, made some changes, and submitted a pull request.  Before the pull request was accepted, I noticed a collaborator of the original branch pushed a commit into my forked branch.  Then the pull request was accepted with the changes I made and he made in my forked branch.  How is is possible that he was able push onto my forked branch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the pull request create page there's a checkbox (checked by default) that is "Allow edits from maintainers".  This enables maintainers to push changes to your branch before merging.

Here's what it looks like in the current UI:

[image: pull request checkbox]